# Horizontal and Vertical linear layout inside a scroll view

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to get a combination of *Views* established. They must constantly have a *Button* and *Edittext* box at the top *horizontally* next to each other and below that a *vertical* list of *Textviews*. The vertical list should be enclosed in a *ScrollView* to allow the user to scroll down through the *TextViews* (The *Button* and *EditText* at the top should still be visible while this is happening).

```
protected void initLayout() {
    // Declaring the vertical layout
    verticalLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    verticalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            //Declaring the horizontal layout
    horizontalLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            //set the main view as horizontal at the top
    setContentView(horizontalLayout);
            //Declaring the scroll view
    ScrollView scrollView= new ScrollView(this); 
    scrollView.addView(verticalLayout);
            //set the scroll view
    setContentView(scrollView);
    //declare and add button to horizontal view
    theButton= new Button(this);
    theButton.setText("Add Joke");
    horizontalLayout.addView(theButton);
    //declare and add edittext to horizontal view
    theEditText= new EditText(this);
    theEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    horizontalLayout.addView(theEditText);
}
```

I believe I might be going wrong with the setContentView but amn't completely sure.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is going wrong with your code? What is the outcome you're getting and how different is it regarding intended result?

Comment: Thanks. The code is displaying the edit texts, the button and edit text are not displaying though. The intended result is for the edittext and button to be at the top and stay there as the user scrolls through the textviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. I had to encapsulate both the horizontal layout and vertical layout inside of another linear layout and set that as the root view.

```
protected void initLayout() {
    // Declaring the vertical layout
    verticalLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    verticalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    //Declaring the horizontal layout
    horizontalLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    //***SOLUTION*** Create a view to group the other views in
    groupLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    groupLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);//vertical as the horizontal view is on top of the vertical view

    //Declaring the scroll view
    ScrollView scrollView= new ScrollView(this); 
    scrollView.addView(verticalLayout);//the vertical layout is the only view that should be scrollable and therefore added to the scrollview

    //declare and add button to horizontal view
    theButton= new Button(this);
    theButton.setText("Add Joke");
    horizontalLayout.addView(theButton);
    //declare and add edittext to horizontal view
    theEditText= new EditText(this);
    theEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    horizontalLayout.addView(theEditText);

    //***SOLUTION*** attach the views to the group view
    groupLayout.addView(horizontalLayout); //the layout displayed at the top of the group layout
    groupLayout.addView(scrollView); //the layout below the top (scrollview already contains the vertical view)

    setContentView(groupLayout);//assign the group layout to the content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your parent ViewGroup must be one. you are using 2 times setContentView and this is your mistake. use only one and add other linearlayout as child in another one.
I think it's better that you try to do in in xml and then write your code like that.

Comment: how can i set the view group so that the horizontal layout is always present at the top and that the vertical layour is below the horizontal layout but can be scrolled through?

Answer (score 0):

basically you've got the setContentView wrong...
i would strongly suggest to define the layout in xml - and then set it just once with the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_xml_layout);
```

this way - you normally do have the possibility to see your layout, and it's (in my opinion) easyer to define a layout (especially if you'll decide to change this one day).

if you wan't to do it in code however, what you'll have to do is something like the following (untested - but should work)

```
protected void initLayout() {
// Declaring the vertical layout
verticalLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
verticalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//Declaring the horizontal layout
horizontalLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
verticalLayout.addView(horizontalLayout); //add the Horizontal-View to the parent-grid

//Declaring the scroll view
ScrollView scrollView= new ScrollView(this); 
scrollView.addView(verticalLayout);
//set the scroll view
verticalLayout.addView(scrollView); //add the scrollview to the parent-grid
//declare and add button to horizontal view
theButton= new Button(this);
theButton.setText("Add Joke");
horizontalLayout.addView(theButton);
//declare and add edittext to horizontal view
theEditText= new EditText(this);
theEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
horizontalLayout.addView(theEditText);
setContentView(verticalLayout);
}
```

edit: sorry - had a few errors in the first time - i edited it now, it should work like this.

Comment: thanks for the help. your advice helped me to get the view i wanted (the button and edittext at the top) but the scroll view doesnt allow me to scroll through the textviews in the vertical layout. i think maybe there is a problem with lines 15 and 17 of your edited code where it seems to add the sccrollview and the vertical layout to each other. if you can provide anymore advice that would be great

Comment: ah it is scrolling ok but the problem i have is that the horizontal layout is scrolling out of view when scrolling through the textviews. is it possible for the horizonal layout to stay at the top of the screen while scrolling through the vertical layout?